# Sine wave frequency estimation with scipy.least_squares on Python

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, non-linear-regression

I am trying to estimate the sine wave frequency using `scipy.least_squares` with Python.  I cannot understand why it does not work.
My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def generate_data(t, A0, A, omega, phase):
    y = A0 + A * np.sin(omega * t + phase)
    return y


#  Init params
A0 = 0
A = 7.744444
omega = 2*np.pi*1 #2*np.pi*0.2
phase = np.pi/2
t_min = 0
t_max = 100
#  Model of sine
t_model = np.linspace(t_min, t_max, 100)
y_model = generate_data(t_model, A0= A0, A=A, omega=omega, phase=phase)
plt.plot(t_model,y_model)

#  Target func
def fun(x, t, y):
    return (x[0]*np.sin(x[1] * t + x[2])) - y


x0 = np.ones(3)
res_lsq = least_squares(fun, x0, args=(t_model, y_model))

res_robust = least_squares(fun, x0, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(t_model, y_model))
print('res_robust.x,',res_robust.x[1], 'expect:',omega)
print('res_lsq.x = ', res_lsq.x[1], 'expect:',omega)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "it dosn't work"?

Comment: Frequency and other parameters are estimated incorrectly

Comment: Please also include all your imports so that one can easily copy&paste code. Please also elaborate on why you think that the parameters are estimated incorrectly (expected vs. actual outcome).

Comment: Your initial estimate is quite far away from the true parameters. Do things improve if you give a better estimate? Moreover you look to be sampling once a second, yet wanting to estimate a 7Hz signal. You should consider nyquist

Comment: Many thanks to all for answers! I found the bug) Problem here: t_max = 100 )) Of course it should be 1..